# Get latest thread and post (reply) on the display forum page

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

This is my Categories_model so far:

```
<?php
class Categories_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function get_categories($parent = NULL) {
        $this->db->from('categories')->where('parent', $parent)->order_by('position');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();  
    }

}
```

SQL STRUCTURE:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `position` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `posts` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `body` text NOT NULL,
  `created` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `threads` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `body` text NOT NULL,
  `created` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

My controller before I load the view who display all categories/subcategories:

```
$data['categories'] = $this->categories_model->get_categories();
$forum = array();

foreach ($data['categories'] as $category) {
    $forum[$category['id']] = $this->categories_model->get_categories($category['id']);
}

$data['subcategories'] = $forum;

$this->template
        ->title('Forum')
        ->build('home', $data);
```

**I want to get the latest Thread and the reply to the thread... in every "subcategory" that is displayed on the Homepage. But I am not quite sure how to do that, how would a method or SQL look like and where do Implement it in my current code?**

Basically:

A Forum Sub Category     (Latest Post)
Category 2                 (Thread 2) a link
                                 a link (Go to latest reply)

Is what I try to achieve, but I am clueless how to do it.

(Display page)

```
        <table class="tborder" width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="6" border="0" align="center">
            <thead>
                <tr align="center">
                    <td class="thead">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="thead" width="100%" align="left">Forum</td>
                    <td class="thead">Senaste inlägg</td>
                    <td class="thead">Ämnen</td>
                    <td class="thead">Inlägg</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
<?php
foreach ($categories as $row) {
?>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tcat" colspan="5">
                        <a href="forumdisplay.php?f=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
<?php
    foreach ($subcategories[$row['id']] as $sub_row) {
?>
            <tbody>
                <tr align="center">
                    <td class="alt2">
                        Ikon
                    </td>
                    <td id="f<?php echo $sub_row['id']; ?>" class="alt1Active" align="left">
                        <div>
                            <a href="forumdisplay.php?f=<?php echo $sub_row['id']; ?>">
                                <strong><?php echo $sub_row['title']; ?></strong>
                            </a>
                            <span class="smallfont">(0&nbsp;besökare)</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="smallfont"><?php echo $sub_row['description']; ?></div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="alt2">
                        <div class="smallfont" align="left">
                            <div>
                                <span style="white-space:nowrap">
                                    <img class="inlineimg" border="0" alt="" src="images/icons/icon1.gif">
                                    <a title="Gå till det första olästa inlägget i ämnet 'Ämne 1'" style="white-space:nowrap" href="#">
                                        <strong>Ämne 1</strong>
                                    </a>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div style="white-space:nowrap">
                                av
                                <a rel="nofollow" href="#">Medlem</a>
                            </div>
                            <div align="right" style="white-space:nowrap">
                                0000-00-00
                                <span class="time">00:00</span>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img class="inlineimg" border="0" alt="Gå till det senaste inlägget" src="#" title="Gå till det senaste inlägget">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="alt1">0</td>
                    <td class="alt2">0</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
<?php
    }
}
?>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create an extra field: last_post_time in table threads. Everytime a new post is created, this field is updated. It's not normal form, but by far the easiest for a forum application.

Answer (score 0):

### Retrieving latest posts

**For this i would query the db like so:** order `DESC` by `id` and retrieve `id`. Since you are inserting a new row, the `id` will `auto_increment` and all you'd need to do is get in `DESC` order.

```
<?php
// This is a model
public function getPosts(){
  $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
  $q = $this->db->get('posts');

  //Make sure we returned something.
  if($q->num_rows() > 0){
    return $q->result();
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

### Retrieving latest Categories

**For this i would add a `last_posted` field:** `last_posted int(11) unsigned NOT NULL` and use `time()` when you update the post or category. Then fetch based on that `last_posted`

```
<?php
// This is a model - get latest category
public function getLastPostedCategories(){
  $this->db->order_by('last_posted', 'DESC');
  $q = $this->db->get('categories');

  //Make sure we returned something.
  if($q->num_rows() > 0){
    return $q->result();
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

### Updating Categories

**For this i would run two queries, one to insert the new post and one to update the category you selected:** I am only showing you the update categories part.

```
<?php
// this is a model - add the last_posted timestamp to a category
public function updatePostDate($cid){
  // i like to check to make sure, $cid is set.. you could do this in the controller too.
  if($cid){
    $this->db->where('id', $cid);
    $this->db->update('categories', array( 'last_posted' => time() ));
    // Make sure we updated the category
    if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```